# `npm` and `node` not working on AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laradock

Story:
I have built a docker image in my local which is `laradock/workspace`.
I can use the `npm` and `node` inside the docker image in my local.
I uploaded the same image at AWS EC2 Container and use it at AWS CodeBuild.

Problem:
But when I do the `node -v` inside the `buildspec.yml` it is not working and always return a status 127.

Reference:
Here is the simple code for my buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm -v
      - node -v
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this?